# Concatenate input from two different files into a separate file

Tags: string, file, python-3.5, linecache

I want to generate the following line(s)

```
1 & {\QPCSymbols\XeTeXglyph 2}  & \textarabic{الحمدلله} & \texttt{!} & \verb$\XeTeXglyph 2$  \\
\hline
```

Let's say the first number is `n` and the second one is `n+1`, the contents of `\textarabic` is obtained from `f_nusoos` and the contents of `\texttt` from `f_keys`. Both files have the same number of lines.

I've created a Python3 script that should get me what I want but I end up with new line symbols (`\n`).

Here is what I have so far,

```
#! python3
import linecache

f_nusoos = 'symbol_nass_list.txt'
f_keys   = 'symbol_key_list.txt'
contentfile = open('content.tex', 'w+', encoding="utf-8")

theLine = " "

for x in range(3):
  contentfile.write('{} & {{\QPCSymbols\XeTeXglyph {}}}  & \\textarabic{{{}}} & \\texttt{{{}}} & \\verb$\XeTeXglyph {}$  \\\\'.format(x+1, x+2,linecache.getline(f_nusoos, x+1).rstrip('\n'), linecache.getline(f_keys, x+1), x+2).rstrip('\n'))
  contentfile.write('\hline')
```

The contents of `content.tex` after execution is,

```
1 & {\QPCSymbols\XeTeXglyph 2}  & \textarabic{بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم} & \texttt{!
} & \verb$\XeTeXglyph 2$  \\\hline2 & {\QPCSymbols\XeTeXglyph 3}  & \textarabic{بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم} & \texttt{"
} & \verb$\XeTeXglyph 3$  \\\hline3 & {\QPCSymbols\XeTeXglyph 4}  & \textarabic{بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم} & \texttt{#
} & \verb$\XeTeXglyph 4$  \\\hline
```

My expectation, however,

```
1 & {\QPCSymbols\XeTeXglyph 2}  & \textarabic{بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم} & \texttt{!} & \verb$\XeTeXglyph 2$\\
\hline
2 & {\QPCSymbols\XeTeXglyph 3}  & \textarabic{بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم} & \texttt{"} & \verb$\XeTeXglyph 3$\\
\hline
3 & {\QPCSymbols\XeTeXglyph 4}  & \textarabic{بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم} & \texttt{#} & \verb$\XeTeXglyph 4$\\
\hline
```

The problem seems to be a new line being inserted after `texttt{CONTENT`. I don't know why this is.

Content of `f_nusoos.txt`:

```
بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم
بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم
بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم
```

Content of `f_keys.txt`:

```
!
"
#
```

Comment: Could it be that the end-of-line character is not `\n`, but `\r\n` (Windows) or `\r` (MacOS)? This would explain why `rstrip('\n')` does not work. Maybe `rstrip()` without parameter is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I was staring at this for too long.

Instead of

```
contentfile.write('{} & {{\QPCSymbols\XeTeXglyph {}}}  & \\textarabic{{{}}} & \\texttt{{{}}} & \\verb$\XeTeXglyph {}$  \\\\'.format(x+1, x+2,linecache.getline(f_nusoos, x+1).rstrip('\n'), linecache.getline(f_keys, x+1), x+2).rstrip('\n'))
```

it should be

```
contentfile.write('{} & {{\QPCSymbols\XeTeXglyph {}}}  & \\textarabic{{{}}} & \\texttt{{{}}} & \\verb$\XeTeXglyph {}$  \\\\'.format(x+1, x+2,linecache.getline(f_nusoos, x+1).rstrip('\n'), linecache.getline(f_keys, x+1).rstrip('\n'), x+2))
```

The `rstrip()` should be for the input from the file and not for the counter.